# Mismatch Date & Time with Reminder

Tags: java, android

I've built one small reminder app demo, where user fill some details and get notified.
When I set the notification time, after current time to 5 minutes later like if current time is 14:55, then I'm setting 15:00  with current date.
Now, notification is coming perfectly on time, when I do nothing and simply wait for 5 minutes to over.

But, when I manually go to my Android phone, and set time to 4 minutes later (14:59) and after wait for 1 minutes, notification is not coming. Why?

**code:**

```
public void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int ID) {
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Put Reminder ID in Intent Extra
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // Calculate notification time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
        long diffTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;

        // Start alarm using notification time
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + diffTime,
                mPendingIntent);

        // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with "when I manually go to my Android phone, and set time to 4 minutes later (14:59)"

Comment: @LppEdd It means I test on my android phone, and in that phone settings-date & time - I changed time to 14:59 FRO 14:55 (current time)

Comment: notification is coming perfectly on time, is this on android phone?

Comment: I'm testing my App in Android Oreo