# How can we check that if alarm is exist / created in our Android phone / my app or not

Tags: android

I've built one small reminder app demo. Now the problem is sometimes reminder coming or sometimes not? Now, I have this feature that user can set the alarm for day, month, week, year.

Now how can I check for the month or year that notification is coming or not?

Obviously, when I manually go and change the Android date and time settings, alarm not coming. (Even for some minutes also)

See: [When I change Android phone date and time, notification not getting, otherwise, if I do nothing, I get notification on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413304/when-i-change-android-phone-date-and-time-notification-not-getting-otherwise)

**Edit:
Code:**

```
public void setRepeatAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int ID, long RepeatTime, int requestCode) {
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Put Reminder ID in Intent Extra
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));


        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
         isAlarmSet = (mPendingIntent != null);
         if (isAlarmSet) {
             showLog("isAlarmSet: " + isAlarmSet);
         } else {
             showLog("isAlarmSet: " + isAlarmSet);
         }
        // Calculate notification timein
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
        long diffTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;

        // Start alarm using initial notification time and repeat interval time
        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + diffTime,
                RepeatTime, mPendingIntent);

        // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Comment: `sometimes reminder coming or sometimes not`? What does that mean

Comment: This scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258407/mismatch-date-time-with-reminder

Comment: @ManojPerumarath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258407/mismatch-date-time-with-reminder

Answer (score 0):

You can check for existing alarm using this :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode,
           new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class),
           PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
boolean isAlarmSet = (pendingIntent!=null);
```

Note that the **requestCode** here should be the same one used while setting the alarm. Also, **AlarmReceiver** is your BroadcastReceiver class for alarm

---

I have not tested this in the scenario you mentioned (changing the phone time), but you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230951/6671004) and set your alarm again according to the new time and cancel the previous one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, Please check my edits, it is returning true, but I'm setting this also: 
         PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT,  is it correct?

Comment: @PoojaSingh, I tried to reproduce this scenario, I too got isAlarmSet as true.

Comment: See, we're just checking that pendingIntent is null or not, that doesn't mean that our alarm will come on correct time & date? How can I ensure? can I check something on my Android phone, any system file or something, that store this alarm information?

Comment: I suggest you to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android/6230951#6230951 and reset your alarms accordingly, if you want to persist alarms on time change.

Also, please use a separate object of PendingIntent (in your code added to question) for checking isAlarmSet as you're using the same object to set an alarm later.

Comment: _that doesn't mean that our alarm will come on correct time & date?_ **correct.**
_can I check something on my Android phone?_ **unfortunately, you cannot query AlarmManager for current Alarms**

Comment: When I create separate object of pending intent, it is returning false

Comment: That would be because you might not be using the **same** requestCode/ID i.e, the 2nd parameter in PendingIntent.getBroadcast(). Please use the same one and check again

Comment: I hv two class, one is main activity from where I call setRepeatAlarm method, and other is AlarmReceiver class which extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver and in this class setRepeatAlarm is written

Comment: Okay, then just move your first '_mPendingIntent =_' statement after _else {showLog("isAlarmSet: " + isAlarmSet);}_.

This should do the trick

Comment: Still showing false, I don't understand, that where we're checking request code, I pass 1 as a request code in this method parameter. That's it (check the last param)

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty knowledge about Design Pattern. Please follow the Observer Pattern to mange below thing and get always new time when you change time manually or not. It will check current time is changed or not. More details Please read Observer Pattern Documentation.

```
// Calculate notification timein
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
        long diffTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;
```

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to time changes in the android system and act accordingly

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeChangedReceiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Broadcast receiver class

```
public class TimeChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
//Call your Alarm setting code
 // change your alarm accordingly
    }
}
```

Comment: I added, but not working in this scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258407/mismatch-date-time-with-reminder